# nav li border off centered in safari

Tags: html, css

Usually Im in AS3 forums but I'm trying to polish my CSS skills. I'm attempting to create a site. But I'm have compatiblity issues with safari. My nav list has a border and I used a padding to make the border larger and centered on the text. But in safari, the border is pushed left.

First question is can anyone help?
Second question is what books or what resources are best to learn Cross Browser Compatibility?

```
    <html>
    <head>

            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
                <!-- Internet Explorer HTML5 enabling code: -->

                <!--[if IE]>
                <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

                <style type="text/css">
                .clear {
                  zoom: 1;
                  display: block;
                }
                </style>


                <![endif]-->
        <title>Antonn Harden Jr | Interactive Designer</title>
        <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
        <script>



    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }
    body {
        line-height: 1;
    }
    ol, ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    blockquote, q {
        quotes: none;
    }
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
        content: '';
        content: none;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }



    body {
        font-family: 'DroidSansRegular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1em;
        background-color: #999999;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y:scroll; /*** scrollbar **/
    }

    p{
        line-height:1.5em;
        padding-bottom:1em;
        color: #fff;
    }

    a, a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:#ffffff;
        outline: none;
    }

    a:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }

    h2, h3, h4{
        line-height: 1.5;
        text-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #333;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    h2, h3, h4, nav{
        font-family: 'ArchitectsDaughterRegular';   
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'ArchitectsDaughterRegular';
        src: url('architects-daughter-fontfacekit/ArchitectsDaughter-webfont.eot');
        src: url('architects-daughter-fontfacekit/ArchitectsDaughter-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('architects-daughter-fontfacekit/ArchitectsDaughter-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('architects-daughter-fontfacekit/ArchitectsDaughter-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('architects-daughter-fontfacekit/ArchitectsDaughter-webfont.svg#ArchitectsDaughterRegular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'DroidSansRegular';
        src: url('ds/DroidSans-webfont.eot');
        src: url('ds/DroidSans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('ds/DroidSans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('ds/DroidSans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('ds/DroidSans-webfont.svg#DroidSansRegular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }

    .line{
        height:1px;
        background-color:#FFF;
        width: 100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

    .clear:after{
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        height: 70px;
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
    }



    /***      HEADER      ***/

    #wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        width: 960px;   
    }

    header { 
        position:relative;
        bottom:0;
    }

    #logo {
        padding: 50px 0 0 12px;
    }

    nav a {
        padding: 3px 14px;  
    }

    nav ul{
        font-size: 20px;
        float: right;
        margin: -10px 0 0 0;
    }

    nav ul li {
      padding: 0 6px;
      list-style: none;
      float: left;
    }

    nav a:hover {
        outline: medium none;
        background-color:#990505;
        color: #fff;
    }



    nav ul li a.current {
        background-color: #990505;
    }

/**** ABOUT ****/

section#about {
    padding-top: 25px;
}

#content {
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 61%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #FFF;    
}

section#about aside{
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    width: 20%;
}

section#about aside h3 {
    font-size: 18px;    
}

section#about aside ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

section#container aside ul li{
    margin: 2px 0;  
}


/***       FOOTER      ****/

footer {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 50px; 
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}


footer h4{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 680px;
    color: #990505;
    font-size: 20px;
}

footer ul {
    float:right;

}

footer ul li {
    padding: 0 3px; 
    display: inline;
}

        </script>
        </head>
        <body>

                <header>

                    <div id="wrapper">

                        <div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="home"></a></div>

                        <nav> 


                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.html"> home </a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html" class="current"> about </a></li>
                                <li><a href="work.html"> work </a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html"> contact </a></li>
                            </ul>


                       </nav>
                   </div>

                </header>

                </section>

                <section id="about">

                    <div id="wrapper">

                         <article id="content">   

                            <p>
                                Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus 
                            </p>

                            <p>
                                Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
                            </p>

                        </article><!--- content -->

                        <div class="clear"></div>

                    </div>

             </section>


            <footer>

                <div id="wrapper">

                    <h4>Follow Me</h4>

                    <ul id>
                        <li><a href="" TARGET="_blank"><img src="./icons/facebook_alt.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="" TARGET="_blank"><img src="./icons/linkedin_alt.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="" TARGET="_blank"><img src="./icons/twitter_alt.png"></a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

            </footer>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Do you really have to write every single html tag to set the margins at 0? What about `*{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;}`?

Comment: I actually started out with *{ margin: 0; padding: 0}, then someone told me to use the reset.css script which didn't change anything either. Safari still gives this weird margin to my border.

Comment: I don't understand this: "I used a padding to make the border larger and centered". Could you provide a link?

Comment: maybe there is something wrong with my safari settings. I haven't added it to a server yet. Just testing offline. "Could you provide a link". All the code is in the message. What I mean is the code I used to make the border centered and large is not working in all browsers. Where "nav a" starts above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your problem fixed:

```
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 14px;
}
```

Now, there is no book that can walk you through all the peculiarities about each web browser. The only quirks that are worth reading about are for IE 6, 7 and 8, the rest of the browsers behave correctly if you adhere to standards.

Every now and then a bug crops up and rears its ugly head. You will find workarounds. Safari shares the same rendering engine as Chrome, yet the problem was visible only in Safari! So don't worry too much about it, eventually it becomes intuitive enough so that you can make out the fixes yourself.

Comment: Thanks to you as well. Well if there is no book on cross browser compatibility, is there a really good book on CSS standards so I don't have to keep coming so much here. I am really good at fixing Actionscript 3.0 bugs, but CSS is another monster. I haven't had much tribulation with it as much. But anyway, thanks again for the advice.

Comment: Eric Meyer on CSS is a pretty authoritative book. http://www.ericmeyeroncss.com/about-book.html.

Answer (score 3):

Well your very first issue. Is that in your code you have used a `<script>` tag for your css instead of a `<style>` tag.

Assuming the first issue is just an error that happened in copying across to the site, the way to solve your padding problem is to set `display:block` on the `nav a`:

```
nav a {
    padding: 3px 14px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: oh sorry that is supposed to be style. I was in a hurry adding this all in one code. My actual folder is loading the external .css file. Please forgive and forget that and focus on the messy css inside I have thanks :).

Comment: No worries. As I said above that css should fix your problem.

Comment: Yep that did it. I was afraid my whole script was all messed up. I have a jQuery banner that is still raised in safari thats causing the nav to not have a hover, but I think that can be fixed with spacing. Thanks a lot.